# Finitely Generated Matrix Group Decompositions

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

If I take a finite collection of n x n invertible matrices and generate a group G under matrix multiplication, is it the case that there always exists a maximal normal solvable group R from which I can decompose G into G = S * R for some other group S? Furthermore, given numerical matrices and assuming that type of decomposition exists, is it feasible to determine if S is a subgroup of U(n) the n x n unitary matrices?

Basically, I would like to get something similar to the Levi decomposition for a Lie Algebra but for matrix groups under multiplication. I was wondering if anyone could point me towards some theorems that might be helpful.

Comment: There is always a maximal normal solvable subgroup. But it is certainly not true that every matrix group decomposes as a free product. Why would you expect that to be true? The group could be the direct product of a solvable group and a free group for example.

Comment: Sorry, my group theory is a bit rusty; I didn't realize that the notation "S * R" implied free product. I don't particularly need it to be a free product, my goal is to be able to write any element of G as a (not necessarily unique) matrix product of something from a subgroup S and something from the maximal normal solvable subgroup, R. If I know that the maximal normal solvable subgroup always exists, could I just take S to be G / R? Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For connected linear algebraic groups over a field $k$ one has indeed a Levi decomposition, provided $k$ has characteristic zero. A *Levi factor* then is a reductive complement to the unipotent radical of the group.
In prime characteristic there may be no Levi factor. For a discussion see, for example, the article [Levi decompositions of a linear algebraic group](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.2777.pdf) by G. M. Mcninch, section $3$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I'm weary that the Levi decomposition will work since, to my knowledge, generating a group from finitely many matrices won't produce a connected group (we can assume that the spec of the generating matrices are all in the unit circle, if that would help). 

The [multiplicative Jordan-Chevally decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Chevalley_decomposition) might work, since my goal is to write every group element as a product of "something" times elements from a normal subgroup that can be simultaneously triangularized.